# img src and onmousehover in css3

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

is it possible to make a class for the `src`, `onmouseout` and `onmousehover` in CSS3 ?

```
<img src="http://www.somesite.com//images/g.png" onmouseout="this.src = 'http://www.somesite.com/images/g.png'"  onmouseover="this.src = 'http://www.somesite.com/images/g-colored.png'" />
```

Comment: Please give more context. Are you using some third-party software apart from pure HTML and CSS (what is CS3)? If so, you should add a respective tag.

Comment: sorry that was a typo , i meant CSS3

Comment: What is `@Url.Content`? It's not standard syntax for any of these. Do you mean you want to get these pictures set as the `IMG` `src` value?

Comment: Please post the OUTPUT (your HTML) not your .NET source code. This happens on the client, not the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:hover` pseudo-rule as well as the `background` style attribute with the `url()` function to accomplish this.  Start by using some sort of "blank" tag, then use something like this:

```
#my_tag_id
{
  background: url('/some/url/to/the/default/image.png');
}

#my_tag_id:hover
{
  background: url('/some/url/to/the/hover/image.png');
}
```

This would not use the `src` attribute of the `img` tag, per se, but has the same effect without any Javascript